# Converting AC3 audio to AAC in Audacity

Tags: audacity, aac, ac3

[image]I have a number of Music Videos I am converting from DVD to MP4. Unfortunately I find the audio levels are all different. It is easy enough to get similar audio leves by using Audacity but would prefer to do the conversion AC3 to AAC at the same time then re-muxing to the video.

I have tried to write out AAC files in Audacity , using external ffmpeg conversion, but they only cause VLC to hang and do not play. I think this is because I do not know what to set the container to.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`ffmpeg-normalize`](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize) and run a batch conversion of all video `MP4` files with:

```
ffmpeg-normalize *.mp4 -c:a aac -b:a 192k
```

This will keep the video and normalize the audio using EBU R 128 loudness normalization. It will encode the audio with ffmpeg's internal AAC encoder. The output will be written to a new directory called `normalized`. The output files will be using the MKV container and should be playable in VLC.

If you are on Windows, the `*.mp4` wildcard will not work, see the README for an alternative loop option.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not a part of ffmpeg ad requires python, which always seems to be problematic. .I am  certain that I have the tools already , just need to know how to use them

Comment: In that case please be more specific with your question and show what you have tried in Audacity (configuration) and what exactly happens with VLC.

Comment: You want me to show you that VLC causes he computer to hang? Is that not good enough just saying it? Sounds like you want a screen capture while the computer is hung, impossible.  I think the fundamental 8ssue is selecting the proper container for the AAC file . Added a generic image of the ffmpeg custom export dialog to OP.

Comment: I meant the specific settings you chose for exporting. Your question does not explain what exactly you've tried. Which container did you choose, and which particular settings? Are you running an up to date version of VLC? Also, your question states that VLC hangs, not your entire computer.

Comment: My question was clear and asked about the container. If you really knew about Audacity, you would have indicated the other method of exporting that I later found.

Comment: No, sorry, your question is still unclear. You just said that you "tried to write out AAC files in Audacity", but that's hardly specific enough. You didn't even specify which container you used. Then you added a "generic" (your own words) screenshot. It's hard to diagnose the issue when there's no detailed information about what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Audacity will allow me to write out (without ffmpeg) a m4a container with AAC audio .No ffmpeg required. Hopefully ffmpeg will handle this format. It does seem the bitrate is fixed at 196